# How to solve this equation with a loop?

Tags: python

This is the sequence:

```
1, 2, 3, -1, 7, -10, 3, -73, …
```

and actually it's like this:

```
t(n) = (t(n-3) * t(n-2)) - t(n-1)
```

for example: `-10 = (3 * -1) - 7`.

I used this code but it's not acting like this equation that I have provided.

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 2
n3 = 3
m = eval(input("number: "))
if m < 4:
    if m == n1:
        print(n1)
    elif m == n2:
        print(n2)
    elif m == n3:
        print(n3)
elif m >= 4:
    n4 = (n1 * n2 - n3)
    print(n4)
```

Comment: why do not use the provided equation as you knew it?

Comment: can you please explain more on the equation. What's n there?

Comment: Whenever you are using number sequences in variable names, a list should be a better container for your data.

Comment: I want to stress again, that `eval` should never ever be used for inputting numbers! A bad actor could just as well nuke your pc with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution to finding `t(m)`

```
n = [1,2,3]
m = int(input("number: ")) #eval is a big security risk!!!
while len(n) < m:
    n.append((n[-3] * n[-2] - n[-1]))
print(n[m-1])
```

where n[negative number] is a number from the end of the list.

Results in:

```
1, 2, 3, -1, 7, -10, 3, -73, 43, -262, -2877, -8389, 762163, 23372990, etc.
```

Comment: thanks dude , you just solved my problem . thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this. This is similar to Fibonacci sequence.

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 2
n3 = 3
m = int(input("number: "))
if m < 4:
    if m == n1:
        print(n1)
    elif m == n2:
        print(n2)
    elif m == n3:
        print(n3)
    
else:
    for i in range(3, m):
        temp1, temp2 = n2, n3
        n3 = n1 * n2 - n3
        n1, n2 = temp1, temp2
    print(n3)
```

Comment: A list would have been nicer and more readable than temorary variables. But nice that it is `O(n)` and not `O(3^n)`

Comment: @wuerfelfreak: A list would also waste a bunch of extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
sequence=[1,2,3]

def find_value(n):
    if n < 4:
        return sequence[n-1]
    else:
        count=3
        while count<n:
            sequence.append(sequence[0]*sequence[1]-sequence[2])
            sequence.pop(0)
            count=count+1
        return sequence[-1]

if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input("Enter digit"))
    print(find_value(n))
```

Comment: This woll only work for `m < 1000` because of the recursion-limit. Also the question was for a loop.

Comment: In that case, a list can be used to store the values of the sequence until required number of elements has been populated.
No recursion will be needed.

Comment: Code has been updated to avoid recursion and is memory effecient.

Comment: Way better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A `O(n)` time and space [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) solution:

```py
def t(n):
    arr = [1, 2, 3]
    if n < 3: return arr[n]
    for i in range(n - 3):
        # calculate the next number with your given equation,
        # and push the result into the temp array
        arr.append(arr[-3] * arr[-2] - arr[-1])

    print(arr)  # show arr content, can remove this line
    # return the last item of the array, which is the result
    return arr[-1]


print(t(10))
```

We won't need recursion here and it would be more efficient in both space and time cost.

Answer (score -1):

This can be handled using a recursive approach, like the following:

```py
m = eval(input("number: "))


def recursive_function(n):
    if 1 <= n < 4:
        return n
    else:
        return (recursive_function(n-3) * recursive_function(n-2)) - recursive_function(n-1)

res = recursive_function(m)
print(m)
```

You have to perform checks on your input (e.g. if you input a string, the function will crash).

Comment: This woll only work for `m < 1000` because of the recursion-limit. Also the question was for a loop.